# Using escChar and escQuote in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a string that may consist of some escape characters like  `\" \"`.  For example,

`"this is an \"example\" of what I want to parse"`

I currently have the following parse rule but it cannot handle the escape characters `\"` 
`QuotedString('"',multiline=True)`

There are options for escChar and escQuote and such for the QuotedString class but I am not sure what to use there.

A complete example of what I want to do

```
def test1():
    str_ = QuotedString('"',escChar='\\',multiline=True)
    decl = (Keyword("FIELD1") + str_ + ';') | \
        (Keyword("FIELD2") + str_ + ';') 
    G = OneOrMore(decl)

    s = """
FIELD1 "hello world";

FIELD2 "an example of \"what\" I want to parse";
"""

    print G.parseString(s)
    # Only print ['FIELD1', 'hello \nworld', ';']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstring for QuotedString gives:

```
 |  __init__(self, quoteChar, escChar=None, escQuote=None, multiline=False, unquoteResults=True, endQuoteChar=None)
 |      Defined with the following parameters:
 |       - quoteChar - string of one or more characters defining the quote delimiting string
 |       - escChar - character to escape quotes, typically backslash (default=None)
 |       - escQuote - special quote sequence to escape an embedded quote string (such as SQL's "" to escape an embedded ") (default=None)
 |       - multiline - boolean indicating whether quotes can span multiple lines (default=False)
 |       - unquoteResults - boolean indicating whether the matched text should be unquoted (default=True)
 |       - endQuoteChar - string of one or more characters defining the end of the quote delimited string (default=None => same as quoteChar)
 |
```

Some interactive interpreter experiments:

```
>>> import pyparsing
>>> s = r'''"this is an \"example\" of what I want to parse" '''
>>> pyparsing.QuotedString('"').parseString(s)
(['this is an \\'], {})
>>> pyparsing.QuotedString('"', escChar='\\').parseString(s)
(['this is an "example" of what I want to parse'], {})
```

I can't say that the constructor args for *all* the classes are 100% complete, but probably >90%.

Comment: Hi Pau, I don't believe this escChar = '\\' does what I want,  I've put a more complete example in the original post -- could you take a look ?  Thanks

Comment: Paul,  I noticed that you added 'r'  in front of my original string -- that would make \"  appear as \"  instead of as an escape for " .  How would I parse my original string ?  Thanks,

Comment: In your given string, without the leading 'r', '\"' the '\' escapes the '"' character to the Python interpreter, and so there is no '\' in the string itself, just '"', which ends up terminating the quotes. (as a test try adding "print '\\' in s", you get back False) Since there is no actual '\' in the string, pyparsing interprets the '"' before 'what' as the end of the quoted string, but fails because there is no terminating ';'. Putting a ';' before the 'w' in 'what', and you will see that the '\' is escaping the '"' to the Python interp. Another test: try ''' " ''' == ''' \" ''' - its True.

Comment: ^ I think this is the crux of the confusion. Another option: create a text file with a string like you want, and read it from the file. The Python interpreter won't interpret the escaping '\'s this way and you will get a string with escaped "s in it.

Comment: got it -- thanks for the explanation Paul.  using the escChar='\\'  I was able to read the string correctly from a file (which is what I need).